# Possible to make tabs that link to discrete HTML files and that don't reload entire page?

Tags: css, menu, tabs

I need menu tabs that link to separate HTML files on my server, with unique URLs. I know this by itself doesn't require anything but CSS, but I would also like to retain the "instant load" effect of Javascript-enable menus, as well as loading only the relevant section of the page. (a CSS-only menu, I think, would reload the entire page). Is this possible?

Comment: maybe take a look at jquery-ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with the help of Knockout.js and/or JQuery.

You could do it all with [JQuery using the Tabs plugin provided by JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). You would have to write all of your own CSS so that you don't get the default "tabbed" look but something that resemble a menu.

Or, you could use [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to create a client-side view model with a set of commands that are bound to your menu items. Each command would then trigger a page update, most likely using JQuery.

Here's a very high-level example of how this might work starting with a basic menu:

```
<ul>
 <li data-bind="menuOption1">
 ...
 </li>
</li>
```

A Knockout.js view model

```
var MenuViewModel = function ()
{
  this.menuOption1 = function () {
    // TODO: show the discreet HTML page
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MenuViewModel());
```

How you actually show the page is up to you. It's probably easiest to use a [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to load the page contents.

Comment: thank you, jQuery UI is probably the best solution for my skill level. I've set up a demo at my server here: http://irishhuddle.com//RSS/development-bundle/demos/tabs/ajax.html ... Is it possible, however, to make each tab a unique URL, so that the address bar is a link to the html file loaded by ajax?

Comment: for instance, i want the URL of the first tab to be http://irishhuddle.com/RSS/development-bundle/demos/tabs/ajax/content1.html and not http://irishhuddle.com/RSS/development-bundle/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-1

Comment: Yes. The tabs plugin supports history and bookmarking so that each tab has a unique URL. With AJAX requests, you have to configure the tabs with some load and select options, but it's all documented in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How you make/style the menu does not have any effect on how the pages linked in the menu are loaded once clicked. In order to avoid a page reload upon click, you'll need to make an `ajax` request to that page and load it into your current page.

I suggest using [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so as to avoid cross-browser issues.

Example:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(ev){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $("#results").append(html);
    });

    ev.preventDefalt();
});
```